# Indexing highest score on each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, variable-assignment

I have a matrix NxN. I need to take the max value of each row. But the problem is that it's part of an assignation problem, in which you can't take the same elements in the columns. I need to assign "task" represented on the x-axis, to the workers represented on the y-axis. Each coordinate of the matrix is a score representing how good is that choice. For example it could be an optimization problem, and the scores are representing the efficiency on each task.

So I have the next case Score:
SCORES_MATRIX is an np.array of shape 2,3 with the following values:

```
    ----------task1 task2 task3
    worker1    [[ 3 5 1 ]
    worker2     [ 2 4 8 ]]
```

I made it with the following code:

```
    NOT_REPEATED_INDEX = []
    for SCORES_VECTOR in SCORES_MATRIX:
        SORTED_VECTOR_INDEXES = np.flipud(np.argsort(SCORES_VECTOR,axis=0))
        for i in range(NUM):
            if SORTED_VECTOR_INDEXES[i] not in NOT_REPEATED_INDEX:
                NOT_REPEATED_INDEX.append(SORTED_VECTOR_INDEXES[i])
                break
```

that would return me:

```
    [1,2]
```

So I need to assign to worker one the second task, and to the worker two the job ride. I have made it like this, but I don't think it's efficient.

Comment: This is not clear to me.  What is to be optimized, what represents the "fleet", how are drivers "assigned", and what do the numbers represent in the two lists?  By the way "assignation" means "an appointment to meet someone in secret, typically one made by lovers," which leads to interesting speculations about what you mean by the "scores."

Comment: Sorry mate. I'm will try to rephrase and rethink it. I will make it more clear and abstract.